# Return category labels for a categorical series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am using pandas for extracting the categories of a dataset like in the following code:

```
data=pd.read_csv("iris.csv",header=None)
data[4]=data[4].astype("category")
```

When I print the values of data[4] I got this list:

```
1         Setosa
2         Setosa
3         Setosa
4         Setosa
5         Setosa
6         Setosa
7         Setosa
...
149    Virginica
150    Virginica
Name: 4, Length: 150, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Setosa, Versicolor, Virginica]
```

but I want to have the three categories in an array so to have something like:

```
[Setosa, Versicolor, Virginica]
```

I was looking around, but I could not find anything that could serve.

Any help?

Comment: it is because the values are on the fourth column, how can I extract the non-repeated values in an array?

Comment: your data are already category? There is no problem with what you are doing

Comment: the problem is that I do not know how to call the categories values, because it prints all. I would like to do something like data[4].getcategories() and return an array of [s,v,vi]

Comment: dtype category helps decrease memory use type `data.info(verbose=True)` before and after changing dtype to category and check How much computer memory is saved!

Answer (score 0):

`data[4].cat.categories.values` might be superior here, versus `.unique()`.

Take a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html, "Working with categories".

> Note: The result of unique() is not always the same as
>   Series.cat.categories, because Series.unique() has a couple of
>   guarantees, namely that it returns categories in the order of
>   appearance, and it only includes values that are actually present.

`.cat.categories.values` seems much faster, because of the reasons listed above I imagine.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], 1000), dtype = "category")

% timeit a = s.unique()

# 303 µs ± 23.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

% timeit b = s.cat.categories.values

# 1.26 µs ± 27.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

print(s.cat.categories.values)

# ['a' 'b' 'c']
```

The size of your dataset and other requirements will likely determine which is better.